# How to detect the which button triggered the event in Kendo UI Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have two or more buttons on [Kendo UI Window](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index), which all will call `.close()` event sooner or later after some business logic.

For example, below screen: '**Close**' button will directly close the window but '**Save**' button will check some condition and then trigger the close.

[image]

Now, I have added my conditions on

```
that.bind('close', function(){
     //check some condition
     // here if condition met, let the flow continue else call preventDefault()
});
```

This interception triggers when both the button is clicked. How do I check which button triggered the event?

FYA, I have extended the Kendo UI Window widget hence the `that.bind()` interception is in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#closeBtnId").bind("click", function () {

});

$("#saveBtnId").bind("click", function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding an event in your function and that should allow you to check who's calling that function. Something like this:

```
that.bind('close', function(e){
         var clickedButton = e.currentTarget || e.target || e.sender;
         //check some condition
         // here if condition met, let the flow continue else call preventDefault()
    });
```